# Is dynamic_cast a bad practice in this context?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, polymorphism

So I have been looking at numerous `dynamic_cast` questions, and it is generally considered a bad practice. I am not sure if using it is a good choice for my code.

So I want to implement matrix multiplication, for both dense and sparse matrices. Here is the base class:

```cpp
class Matrix{
    protected:
    uint cols, rows;

    public:
    Matrix(uint rows, uint cols) : rows(rows), cols(cols){};

    virtual std::unique_ptr<Matrix> operator * (const Matrix & rhs);
    
    virtual void setValue(uint row, uint col, double value) = 0;
    virtual double getValue(uint row, uint col) const = 0;

    uint getCols() const {return cols;}
    uint getRows() const {return rows;}
};
```

I then define a dense matrix class, which is unimportant here, and define
dense multiplication as the standard multiplication algorithm.

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<Matrix> Matrix::operator*(const Matrix & rhs){
    std::unique_ptr<Matrix> result(new DenseMatrix(getRows(), rhs.getCols()));

    for(uint i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        for(uint k = 0; k < rhs.getRows(); k++){
            for(uint j = 0; j < rhs.getCols(); j++){
                result->setValue(i, j, result->getValue(i, j)+getValue(i, k)*rhs.getValue(k, j));                    
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Now, I want to implement a coordinate sparse matrix, and make it so multiplication of two coordinate matrices is a different algorithm, since it can be done way faster. Here is the idea:

```cpp
class ColCoordinateMatrix : public Matrix{
    //unimportant boilerplate code

    std::unique_ptr<Matrix> operator * (const Matrix & rhs) const override{
        const ColCoordinateMatrix * colRepresentation;
        if(colRepresentation = dynamic_cast<const ColCoordinateMatrix*>(&rhs)){
            //implement and return a much faster multiplication for sparse matrices here
            //return ...;
        }
        return Matrix::operator*(rhs);
    }
}
```

Now I am wondering - dynamic_cast is a bad practice, but I see no other way to resolve this problem. Is it really that bad here?

Comment: How about adding fields containing properties of the matrix to the `Matrix` class. Furthermore depending on the desired use it may actually be better to implement the multiplication outside of the class: If the exact type of the operand types of `*` are known, you could create `tempate<class Operand1Type, class Operand2Type> MultiplicationResult<Operand1Type, Operand2Type> operator(Operand1Type const& o1, Operand2Type const& o2) { ... }` which would allow you to add a specialization for both operand types being `ColCoordinateMatrix`.

Comment: @fabian For some reason I have not thought of implementing the operator outside of the classes, but It is a great idea. Let me try It out in the code.

Comment: You could also look in to [tag:double-dispatch].

Answer (score 0):

There isn't going to be a right or wrong answer here, it really is a matter of style. I'm always slightly weary when people say that a particular language feature is 'bad practice' or 'smells', etc; personally, if `goto`, preprocessor macros, multiple return statements, or any of the 100 other things people tell you not to do make the code clear and easily debuggable, or even if its the only way to solve the problem, then go for it. `dynamic_cast` isn't really a *harmful* feature as such --- it might look a bit odd in C++ code where we generally veer away from using runtime type information to solve a problem, buy hey: once you're using a virtual class the RTTI is already there, so why not use it?

In your particular case, my only qualm would be that this can easily get complicated if you have multiple sparse matrix classes and an efficient algorithm for multiplying every different type with every other type: your multiplication function will get rather long. Maybe implement specific algorithms for multiplying different in separate private functions, and at the top of your function do the checks if the operand is a particular type of matrix then just call an appropriate function.